# Systemd escaping error with asterisk occurs in shell script but not command-line

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, scripting

Running `systemctl --user enable 'foo*'` succeeds from a bash command-line; however, putting that same line in a shell script and running `bash script` yields

```
Invalid unit name "foo_*" was escaped as "foo_\x2a" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Failed to enable unit: Unit file foo_\x2a.service does not exist.
```

Note that my `systemctl` version is `239`. I've seen variants of this problem but they usually revolve around Windows return/carriage return issues ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408385/systemctl-not-working-from-shellscript-but-works-from-terminal)), and not asterisks.

Comment: It doesn't seem it's exactly the same command inside your script. For instance, in your script there's an underscore I don't see on your command. Maybe the extra underscore in your script is the reason. Maybe there are other differences as well not mentioned in your question.  I think you're missing some important details. [edit] your question and copy the **exact** command you run in the shell, and the **exact** content of your bash script. Create a minimal reproducible test case with a real script that people could use to reproduce on they own environment, including your service file.

Comment: @aviro - agreed but note that the 1st command, as posted here, should fail with a similar message, regardless of the pattern used.

Comment: @don_crissti as I said, I feel it's missing some critical information. Maybe he didn't copy here the exact command that he used. Maybe it did write the "Invalid unit name" message but systemctl succeeded. There are just too many unknowns in the question to make any assumptions.

Comment: I'm going to close this because it seems like the command-line behavior is no longer working. I think in general asterisk behavior is spotty. Thanks for the input